# Matlab error after most actions (saving file, closing figure etc.)

Tags: matlab

last week I got a new work computer, it uses Matlab 2016a (Windows 10, Hp). As soon as I save a file, edit a field, close a figure etc. I get the following error (as a dialog box):

```
readonly
First input must be a cell array of character arrays.
strjoin
55
```

I tend to get several identical errors (dialog boxes). When I start perhaps two or three, increasing the longer I use Matlab.

I am really clueless about the source of the error, so would appreciate any hint about what to check for, sensible ways to try to find out what can cause the problem etc. I had no problem when I used Matlab 2016a on my old computer (Windows 7, hp).

Cheers,
Gunnar Larsson

Comment: This is just a bad install. Contact IT, reinstall.

Comment: Ok will do so, thanks!